# What is the number of ways to pick $k$ non-negative integers that add up to $n$? Assume that these are ordered sets.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So the specific question I was asked was to find the number of ways $3$ numbers between $0$ to $99$ can add up to $100$, but I'm curious if this can also be generalized.

So far I've figured out that if we need to add $2$ integers to a number $n$, we simply have $n-1$ different ways as follows:

$1 + n-1$

$2 + n-2$

$3 + n-3$

...

$n-1 + 1$

Edit: I think the stars and bars problem is pretty much the same as my question except im not allowed to use the number 'n' itself. I.e 0+0+100 is not allowed(though 0+50+50 is)

I think my answer would be C(n+k-1, k-1) - k

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This type of question has been asked & answered on this site many times. Please do a search for earlier appearances.

Comment: To be clear, do you consider $20+30+50$ to be different than or the same as $50+20+30$?  Do you allow numbers to be the same, i.e. do you count $30+30+40$?  See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) or [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#Restricted_partition_function) or [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) depending on what restrictions you have.  The most likely interpretation is probably stars-and-bars.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between the problems where you allow zero vs where you do not allow zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz my problem allows zeroes but does not allow n itself (0+50+50 is okay but 0+0+100 is not). I think my answer required would be the value from the stars and bars problem, minus 2. Thanks!

Comment: Minus 3 then since you have 100+0+0, or 0+100+0 or 0+0+100, and minus $k$ in general then.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Thanks!